# add metal support as optionnal renderer in ios App

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, ios8, metal

I'm working on an iOS App with openGL ES rendering. we are working on metal support and we are experiencing a crash at app launch on device with ios 7.1 (we target ios 7.1+ devices)

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal

looks like even if the Metal.framework is still unused in our app, the app tries to load it and crashes as the framework in not a part on ios7.

How can we dynamically link the metal framework only in case device is ios8+ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding linking to Metal.framework as optional resolves the issue.